# Uses of peaks in audio auto-correlation

Tags: audio, autocorrelation, peak-detection

Do you know of any algorithms for audio processing that make use of peaks in auto-correlation function? I am currently involved in research on mapping methodology for dynamic algorithms. I came recently over an algorithm for detection of fundamental frequency in audio signals, which has a dynamic structure I am looking for - the execution time of the algorithm varies with the number of peaks in the signal's auto-correlation:

```
while (i < hsize)

    // Search for peaks in auto-correlation:
    if((r[i] > 0) && (r[i]>r[i-1]) && (r[i]>=r[i+1])){

            temp = 0.25f*(r[i+1]-r[i-1]);
            temp = r[i] - temp*temp/(0.5f*(r[i+1]+r[i-1]) - r[i]);
            n = n1[i] + n2[i];
            if ((rmax*n) < (temp*nmax)) {imax=i; rmax=temp; nmax=n;}.

            i++;}
    else{i++;}
```

This would be perfect as a studying example for my methodology, but the problem is that there is only a couple of lines inside the loop, so the overhead of adding my techniques becomes too big for the problem of this size. Now I am wondering if there exist any similar algorithms in audio processing, i.e. also making use of peaks in auto-correlation function but perform more extensive calculations for each peak?

Comment: Dear colleagues, I am sorry that my post do not have any greeting. I could actually not add any - it disappears from the posted text!

Comment: Elena, i would suggest that many pitch-detection algorithms use some form of auto-correlation and must look at every peak of any significance and make decisions regarding those peaks (like picking just one of the peaks and then interpolating the precise location).

Comment: Thank you Robert! This is a good hint, I will look closer at pitch-detection algorithms!

Comment: @ElenaHammari [Greetings and thanks are automatically removed because they are considered a distraction from the question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989)  Just ask the question and thank people by clicking the upvote arrows.

Answer (score 1):

The YIN Algorithm could be of interest to you. It's based on autocorrelation and is used for estimating the fundamental frequency.

A. de Cheveigné, H. Kawahara: *YIN, a fundamental frequency estimator for speech and music*, Proceedings of ICMC 2005. [Download PDF](http://recherche.ircam.fr/equipes/pcm/cheveign/pss/2002_JASA_YIN.pdf).

A [C++ implementation](http://mroy.chez-alice.fr/yin/index.html) is also available.

Comment: Thank you, Frank! Actually I already have YIN algorithm included in the same library as the algorithm above (which is documented as McLeod/Wyvill normalization scheme). I have profiled the YIN algorithm too, but did not test my methodology on it yet. And it seems that the version of YIN that I have is not the full one (step 6 of the algorithm is excluded), so it is indeed possible to extend further. Thank you for the link to the code!

Comment: I have now checked the YIN algorithm in my library and it still gives the same problem, although the results are better. Hope the full version of the algorithm will help :).

Comment: @ElenaHammari: If this answer helped, please consider accepting it.